# How to assign indexes to your datatable rows in sqlite in large databases?

Tags: sql, database, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm using sqlite with python. Suppose that I have a datatable that looks like this:

```
     Table 1

1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
__|___|___|___|__
A | B | B | C | D
B | D | B | D | C
A | D | C | C | A
B | D | B | D | C
D | B | B | C | D
D | B | B | C | D
```

**Question:** How can I create (very quickly/efficiently/viable for very large databases) an index column for each row where if row x and row y are identical they get assigned the same index? For the example database I would want something like this:

```
        Table 1

Index| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
_____|___|___|___|___|___
  23 | A | B | B | C | D
  32 | B | D | B | D | C
  106| A | D | C | C | A
  72 | B | D | B | D | C
  80 | D | B | B | C | D
  80 | D | B | B | C | D
```

I don't care what the actual indexes are, as long as duplicate rows (like the last two in the example) get the same index.

Comment: Why do you actually need the duplicate rows to be there? Couldn't you just use a table with distinct rows, and a column with the count of duplicates of that row in the original table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You COULD create an index made up of every field in the table.

```
create index on table1 (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5)
```

But that's probably not a good idea. It makes a huge index that will be slow to build and slow to process. Some database engines won't let you create an index where the combination of fields is over a certain length. I'm not sure if there's such a limit in sqllite or what it might be.

The normal thing to do is to pick some field or combination of a small number of fields that is likely to be short and well distributed.

By "short" I mean literally and simply, the data in the field only takes a few bytes. It's an int or a varchar with a small length, varchar(4) or some such. There's no absolute rule about how short "short" is, but you should pick the shortest otherwise suitable field. A varchar(4000) would be a bad choice.

By "well distributed" I mean that there are many different values. Ideally, each row has a unique value, that is, there is no value that is the same for any two rows. If there is no such field, then pick one that comes as close to this as possible. A field where sometimes 2 or 3 rows share a value but rarely more than that is good. A field where half the records all have the same value is not.

If there is no one field that is well distributed, you can create an index on a combination of two or three fields. But if you use too many fields, you start breaking the "short" condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you can parse your file row by row why not use a dict with the row as a string or a tuple?

```
my_dico = {}
index_counter = 1
with open(my_db) as my_database, open(out_file) as out:
    for row in my_database:
        my_row_as_a_tuple = tuple(row.strip().split())

        if my_row_as_a_tuple in my_dico:
            out.write(my_dico[my_row_as_a_tuple] + '<your separator>' + row)

        else:
            index_counter += 1
            out.write(str(index_counter) + '<your separator>' + row)
            my_dico[my_row_as_a_tuple] = str(index_counter)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But isn't this very inefficient for large databases?

Comment: Is depend what you are calling large, for few millions row is should be fine even on a personal computer. but nothing replace actual, test... If your are concern with speed or memory efficiency pure python is may be not the right tool. you can check pypy if you want to stay with python else you may want to go low level with something like c / c++ or rust.

Comment: Ok great then I'll use this one! Just one more question: what would my_db be and what would out_file be? Do you want to write millions of rows to a file?

Comment: And isn't this inefficient in general? Why would you do the checking of the rows in python? Why not do it with sql queries? Isn't that at lot faster?

Comment: I just projected my usual work condition which implies to filter large csv file in python. I'am not use to work with sql so I cannot answer sorry...